# How to put each next two elements under each other with css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

With this HTML:

```
<div class="grid">   
    <h2>Somewhat longer title here</h2>   
    <div class="description">Description here</div>
    <h2>Title 2 here</h2>   
    <div class="description">Description 2 here</div>
    <h2>Title 3 here</h2>
   <div class="description">Description 3 here</div>
    <h2>Title 4 here</h2>
   <div class="description">Description 4 here</div>
   <!-- this may continue with more items -->
</div>
```

Is there a way with css grids to display it like this:

```
title1    title2 
descr1    descr2
title3    title4
descr3    descr4
...       ...
```

So basically having 2 columns and somehow stating that every description takes up the cell underneeth the h2, but the third title still automatically going to a next row.

Comment: Is this layout fixed, or it could have any number for `h2` / `.desc` elements?

Comment: it can have any number of elements